# Java: how to designate a dir so I don't need to specify it in order to reference its .jar files

Tags: java, jar

Let's say that I have a jar file @ `/usr/local/apps/app1/java/file.jar`.  I would like to be able to reference `file.jar` in the `java` command without typing the full path.  For example, `java -jar file.jar`.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; `-jar` requires a jar file argument.

You could create a symlink, or provide a launcher script.

Answer (score 1):

`ln -s /usr/local/apps/apps1/java/file.jar file.jar` would create a symbolic link to the jarfile, which *might* permit the JVM to run the jarfile.  Of course, this would only work within the directory containing the symlink.

There is likely no way to do this generically without using a script.